# Set character set in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

how to do character set in sqlite query.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ty8.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on `do character set`. Do you want to insert a character in a column, update a character in a column, replace a character in an existing column value, ...? Give an example and show us your attempt: a full [minimal, reproducalbe example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the datatype `TEXT`. You can see the datatypes in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).